# Number of solutions of $x^2_1+\dots+x^2_n=0,$ $x_i\in \Bbb{F}_q.$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb F$ be field with $q$ element and $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb F)\neq2$. I want to know about the number of solutions of this equation:

$$x^2_1+x^2_2+\dots+x^2_n=0 \text{ where } x_i\in \mathbb F.$$

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any context for this problem? Motivation? As is, the question appears quite difficult to answer. Even if we take the field to be $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $n$ to be $2$ or $3$ this problem isn't easy.

Comment: Actually, $n=2$ is very easy. If $-1$ is not a square (and that's easy to decide) then there's only 1 solution, else, $2q-1$.

Comment: I have read another equation and I thaugh for this equation. You can look page79 form Classical group and geometric algebra by Grove

Comment: @Ragib: actually this is one of the few families of polynomials for which a reasonably straightforward answer is possible (morally because a variety defined by a homogeneous quadratic polynomial is either empty or birational to projective space). Past the quadratic case things become much harder...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer that works, when $q\equiv1\pmod4$. This is a minor simplification
to the use of recurrences as described in the first sentence of Gerry Myerson's answer
(that I somehow missed as my gaze was drawn to the character sums :/). For the cases
$q\equiv-1\pmod4$ I recommend doing it his way.

---

When $q\equiv1\pmod4$ we know that the field contains a primitive fourth root of unity, call it $i$. Let $A(n)$ be the number of solutions for the equation in $n$ variables. We know (see also comment's by Gerry Myerson) that $A(1)=1$ and $A(2)=2q-1$.

We can write 
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=(x_1+ix_2)(x_1-ix_2)=z_1z_2,$$
where $z_1=x_1+ix_2$ and $z_2=x_1-ix_2$. The mapping $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(z_1,z_2)$ is clearly a bijection, so $A(n)$ is equal to the number of solutions of
$$
z_1z_2=-(x_3^2+x_4^2+\cdots+x_n^2).
$$
Here the r.h.s. is equal to zero for exactly $A(n-2)$ vectors $(x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n)$, so
that gives us $(2q-1)A(n-2)$ solutions. OTOH, if the r.h.s. is non-zero, we can let $z_2$ be any non-zero element ($(q-1)$ choices), and can then uniquely solve for $z_1$. This gives us $(q-1)(q^{n-2}-A(n-2))$ solutions. Altogether we get a recurrence relation
$$
A(n)=(2q-1)A(n-2)+(q-1)\left(q^{n-2}-A(n-2)\right)=(q-1)q^{n-2}+qA(n-2).
$$

It is easy to prove by induction on $n$ that this has the solution
$$
A(2k+1)=q^{2k}
$$
for odd values of $n=2k+1$, and
$$
A(2k)=q^{2k-1}+q^k-q^{k-1}
$$
for even values of $n=2k$.

Comment: This is closely related to the birational equivalence Qiaochu is talking about in his comment.

Answer (score 9):

Let $A_n$ be an abbreviation for $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$. Let $a_n$ be the number of solutions of $A_n=0$, let $b_n$ be the number of solutions of $A_n=-1$, and let $c_n$ be the number of solutions of $A_n=c$, where $-c$ is some fixed nonsquare in the field. Find a system of recurrences involving $a_n$, $b_n$, and $c_n$, and solve.

Alternatively, use exponential sums. This is easiest to do when $q$ is prime. $$\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}\cdots\sum_{x_n}\sum_te^{2\pi it(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)/p}$$ gives $p$ times the number of solutions, where the sums are over all $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,t$ in the field. Bring the sum on $t$ to the front, separate out the term with $t=0$ to get $$p^n+\sum_{t=1}^{p-1}\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}\cdots\sum_{x_n}e^{2\pi it(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)/p}=p^n+\sum_{t=1}^{p-1}\left(\sum_xe^{2\pi itx^2/p}\right)^n$$ The sum on the inside is a quadratic Gauss sum whose value is recorded in many texts and on many websites.

Similar methods apply when $q=p^r$, $r\gt1$, but I disremember the trick.

Note the problem $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$ (over the field of $p$ elements) is done in detail in Ireland and Rosen, A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory, Chapter 8, Section 6, pages 101-102. $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=0$ is left as Exercise 19 in that chapter. The tools for extending the results to finite fields more generally are developed in Chapter 10.

Comment: thanks, I am looking for simple formula for this like the number of k-dimensional subspace of n-dimensional space

Comment: Well, I've shown you two ways to find a formula, and a book that does it for you. I don't know what you consider to be a *simple* formula, and there's no point in looking for one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Garry Myerson I saw this exercise I don't have information about character of order 2. I was wondering if you could tell me explicit formula by p and n.

Comment: Sure, if you can wait a couple of weeks while I try to find the time. In the meanwhile, you could always try to work it out on your own from the information I've already given.

Comment: :I appreciate you if you calculate for me. I looked at page 101 and 102 Modern Number Theory. they use  character of order 2

Comment: A character of order 2 is just a function that is 1 for squares and -1 for non-squares (and zero for zero). Please, try to work out the details of what I've already written. If you get stuck somewhere along the way, I'll help you, but if there's no sign of effort on your part, well then how much do you really care about the problem anyway?

Comment: Gerry Myerson: thanks I am looking for number isotropic subspace and I want to know only the number of this equation

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to answer this in a self-contained manner - I will repeat ideas by Paul and Gerry but it will be more detailed. I'll restrict myself to $q = p$ (a prime), but the same arguments are valid in the general case.

We'll generalize, because the problem calls for it: you want to count solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = 0$ - why not understand the distribution of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$, i.e. how many times each value in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ appears in the multiset $\{ f(\vec{x}) | \vec{x} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{n} \}$.

This problem is a *convolution* problem - let $v$ be the vector that counts solutions to $x^2 = i$ - its i'th coordinate is the number of square roots of $i$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. If we convolve $v$ with itself $n$ times, you'll get the distribution of our function $f$, and you need the 0'th coordinate: $\underbrace{v * \cdots * v}_\textrm{n times}$.

You can approach this via Fourier Transform (so-called "Gauss sums"), since Fourier turns convolution into pointwise multiplication which is easier, but we can avoid that.

The key step is noting that $v*v$ is almost constant - it has a certain value on 0, and another value on all $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$. Why is that?

1. If $p \equiv 1 (4)$, there's a square root of -1 in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, call it $i$. Then the equation $x^2 + y^2 = j$ is equivalent to $(x+iy)(x-iy) = j$. We can make the substitution $x+iy=t, x-iy=s$ (since $char(F) \neq 2$) and this turns to $st = j$. If $j=0$ there are $2p-1$ solution, else - there are $p-1$ solutions ($(s,js^{-1})$).
2. If $p \equiv 3 (4)$, there's no square root of -1 living in our field, but we can construct a quadratic extension of our field, which will contain it - $i \in \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ (as there's a unique quadratic extension of any finite field). The equation $x^2 + y^2 = j$ becomes :
   $$x^2 + y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy) = (x+iy)^{p+1} = j$$
   because $x-iy$ is the conjugate of $x+iy$, and Frobenius Automorphism $t \to t^p$ takes elements to their conjugates. (Since it's linear, you can just verify $1^p = 1, i^p = -i$). We can write this equation as $t^{p+1} = j$ where $j \in \mathbb{F}_{p}, t \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Note that $\mathbb{F}_{p} = (\mathbb{F}_{p^2})^{p+1}$ (one inclusion follows since for $t \neq 0$, $(t^{p+1})^{p-1} = t^{p^2 - 1} = 1$, so $t^{p+1} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$). Since $(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})^{\times}$ is cyclic, for $j \neq 0$ this reduces to the equation 
   $$(p+1)x \equiv (p+1)a (\mod p^2-1)$$
   which has $p+1$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2-1)\mathbb{Z}$. For $j=0$, this clearly has one solution - $t=0$, i.e. $x=y=0$.

So $v*v$ is nice - as a function of $i$, it depends only on whether $i =0$ or not.

*Now, a nice exercise:* Let $u = (a,\underbrace{b, \cdots , b}_\textrm{p-1 times})$. $v = (c,\underbrace{d, \cdots , d}_\textrm{p-1 times})$. Then $u*v = (e,\underbrace{f, \cdots , f}_\textrm{p-1 times})$, where $(e-f) = (a-b)(c-d)$ and $e + (p-1)f = (a + (p-1)b)(c + (p-1)d)$. If $a=c, b=d$, we get: $(e-f)=(a-b)^2, e+(p-1)f = (a+(p-1)b)^2$. This is where the Fourier aspect is hidden - convolution of vectors multiplies the frequencies.

We're really close.

1. If $n$ is even, then $\underbrace{v * \cdots * v}_\textrm{n times} = \underbrace{(v * v) * \cdots * (v*v)}_\textrm{n/2 times}$, and this is easy by the exercise - if we apply the exercise $\frac{n}{2}$ times, our final vector $w$ will be of the form $(a,\underbrace{b, \cdots , b}_\textrm{p-1 times})$, where $a-b = \begin{cases} \ ((2p-1) - (p-1))^{n/2}  &\text{if } p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}\\ ((p+1) - (1))^{n/2} & \text{if } p\equiv 3 \pmod{4} \end{cases} $ and $a+b(p-1) = (p^2)^{n/2}=p^n$. Solving these 2 equation gives $a$, which is the number you're seeking.
2. If $n$ is odd, we first calculate $\underbrace{v * \cdots * v}_\textrm{n-1 times}$ similarly to the first case. Then we need to convolve $(a,\underbrace{b, \cdots , b}_\textrm{p-1 times})$ with $v$, which turns out to be a relatively easy problem: the i'th coordinate will be $(a-b)v_i + pb$ (do it yourself). For $i=0$, $v_i = 1$ and the answer is $a-b+pb = (p-1)b+a$.

So there are 4 cases, depending on whether  $i \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$ ($p \equiv 1(4)$) and on the parity of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get a recursion is by first noting that, whether or not $\sqrt{-1}$ lies in the ground field $\mathbb F_q$, every element of $\mathbb F_q$ is representable as $x^2+y^2$: when there *is* a $\sqrt{-1}$, this factors, and, when there is *no* $\sqrt{-1}$, this is the norm from the quadratic extension $\mathbb F_{q^2}$, which is *surjective*.

To hit $0$, there is a unique solution of $x^2+y^2=0$ without $\sqrt{-1}$, while there are $2q-1$ solutions *with* $\sqrt{-1}$. For non-zero values $z$, there are $q-1$ solutions of $x^2+y^2=z$ with $\sqrt{-1}$, and $q+1$ without.

Thus, there are two families of cases, depending on presence or absence of $\sqrt{-1}$, and incorporating whether one is hitting $0$ or not. That is, looking at $x^2+y^2=1-(x_3^2+\ldots+x_n^2)$, treat the cases that the right-hand side is $0$, or not, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $\operatorname{char}F \ne 2$. Let's denote by $S_n(a)$ the set $\{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in F^n \ | \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = a\}$. We have the stereographic parametrization of the sphere $S_n(1)$ by he map
$$F^{n-1} \ni x \mapsto \left(\frac{x}{1+|x|^2}, \frac{1-|x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\right)\in S_n(1)$$
with inverse $$S_n(1) \ni (x', x_n) \mapsto \frac{x'}{1+x_n}\in F^{n-1}$$
We get in this way a bijection between $S_n(1) \backslash S_{n-1}(0)$ and $F^{n-1} \backslash S_{n-1}(-1)$. Assume now $F$ finite, $|F|=q$. If we write $s_n(a) = \# S_n(a)$ we get
$$s_n(1) - s_{n-1}(0) = q^{n-1} - s_{n-1}(-1)$$

Note that we also have
$$s_n(-1)= \frac{ s_{n+1}(0) - s_n(0)}{q-1}$$

Case 1.  $-1$ is a square in $F$, that is $q\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. We conclude $s_n(1) = s_n(-1)$, and from above we get
$$\frac{s_{n+1}-s_n(0)}{q-1} = q^{n-1}+ s_{n-1}(0) - \frac{s_{n}(0)-s_{n-1}(0)}{q-1}$$
or
$$s_{n+1} (0)-q^n = q \,(s_{n-1}(0)-q^{n-2})$$

Case 2.  $-1$ is not a square, that is $q\equiv -1 \pmod 4$.

Looking at the fibres of the map $F^n \ni (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \in F$, we get
$$q^n = s_(0) + \frac{q-1}{2} s_n(1) + \frac{q-1}{2} s_n(-1)$$

With some calculations we get
$$(s_{n+1}(0) - q^n) = -q \,( s_{n-1}(0) - q^{n-2})$$

So for arbitrary odd $q$ we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{
s_{n+1}(0)- q^n = (-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}} q\,(s_{n-1}(0)-q^{n-2})
}$$

Some conclusions:

if $n$ is odd then $s_n(0) = q^{n-1}$. This follows easily by induction, noting that $s_1(0) = 1$.

To get all of $s_n(0)$ from the recurrence above we also need $s_2(0)$.  If $-1$ is not a square we get $s_2(0) = 1$.  If $-1$ Is a square, then the equation $x_1^2 + x_2^2= 0$ can be transformed into $y_1^2 - y_2^2 = 0$, which has $2q-1$ solutions. So, in general we have

$$s_2(0)-q = (-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}(q-1)$$

the formulas $s_3(0)$ and $s_4(0)$ do not depend on the parity of $\frac{q-1}{2}$. This can be seen from the formulas, or by noting that the projective variety $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_1$, while $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - t^2=0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_1\times \mathbb{P}_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, $A^{\star}$ the group of characters of $A$. We have
$$\sum_{\lambda \in A^{\star}} \lambda(x) = \begin{cases} |A| &\textrm{ if } x = 0 \\
               0   &\textrm{ if }  x \ne 0 
\end{cases}$$

Let $X$ be a finite set, $f\colon X\to A$ a function. Then we have the counting formula
$$\#\{ x \in X \ | \ f(x) = 0\} = \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{ \lambda \in A^{\star},{x \in X}}\lambda(f(x))$$

A particular case is $X= X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$,
$f\colon X\to A$, $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$. We have
$$\#\{ x \in X \ | \ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i) = 0\} = \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{ \lambda \in A^{\star},x \in X}\lambda(\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i))= \\ =\frac{1}{|A|} \sum_{\lambda \in A^{\star} } \prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{x_i \in X_i} \lambda(f_i(x_i))$$

Now consider $A=F$ a finite field of odd order $q$, $X= F^n$, and $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i^2$, where $d_i \in F^{\times}$.

Now from the above we have to understand sums of form
$$\sum_{x\in F} \lambda( a x^2) $$
where $\lambda$ is a character of $F$, $a \in F^{\star}$. If $\lambda$ is the trivial character the sum equals $q$. Assume now $\lambda$ nontrivial.

Lemma: Let $\phi\colon F \to B$, where $B$ is an abelian group, and $\sum_{x\in F} \phi(x)=0$. Then
$$\sum_{x\in F} \phi(x^2)= \sum \mu(x) \phi(x)$$
where $\mu$ is the quadratic character $\mu\colon F \to \{-1,0,1\}\subset \mathbb{C}$.  The proof is immediate. We conclude:
$$\sum_{x\in F} \lambda( a x^2)= \sum_{x\in F} \mu(x) \lambda( a x) = \mu(a)\cdot \sum_{x\in F} \mu(x) \lambda(x)$$

We are now ready to calculate with the formula above. Fix $\lambda$ a nontrivial character of $F$.Then all of the characters of $F$ are $\lambda_a(x) = \lambda(a x)$, for $a \in F$.  The term corresponding to $\lambda_a$, with $a=0$ ( the trivial character) equals $q^n$. The term corresponding to $\lambda_a$, $a \in F^{\star}$ equals

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{x\in X} \lambda( a d_i x^2) = 
\mu(a)^n \mu(d_1 \cdots d_n) (\sum_{x\in X} \mu(x) \lambda(x))^n$$

We get

$$\#\{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in F^n \ | \sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i^2 = 0\} = q^{n-1} +\\ + \frac{1}{q}(\sum_{a \in F^{\times} }\mu^n(a)) \mu(d_1 \cdots d_n) (\sum_{x\in F} \mu(x) \lambda(x) )^n$$

If $n$ is odd, we have $\mu^n = \mu$, a nontrivial character of $F^{\times}$, so $\sum_{a \in F^{\times}} \mu^n(a) = 0$. We conclude that the number of solutions of $\sum d_i x_i^2 = 0$ equals $q^{n-1}$.

Assume now $n$ is even. We get

$$\# \{ x, Q(x) = 0\} = q^{n-1} + \frac{q-1}{q} \mu(\det Q) S^{n}$$
where
$$S = \sum_{x\in F} \mu(x) \lambda(x)$$
is a quadratic Gauss sum. Note that if $\lambda$ is changed to $\lambda_a$, the sum gets multiplied by $\mu(a)$, so $S$ is not determined, but $S^2$ is.

Now, we'll get $S^2$ by estimating
$$\# \{ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0\}$$

If $-1$ is not a quadratic residue there is only one solution $(0,0)$. We get

$$1 = q + \frac{q-1}{q} S^2$$
so $S^2 = - q$

If $-1$ is a quadratic residue, we have $2q-1$ solutions ( of form $(x, \pm \sqrt{-1} x)$) so
$$2q-1 = q + \frac{q-1}{q} S^2$$
and we conclude $S^2 = q$.

Therefore, we have $S^2 = \mu(-1) q$. We can plug this value in the formula for nondegenerate quadratic forms in an even number of variables.

The value $\mu(\det Q)$ is the only invariant of a nondegenerated quadratic form in a given number of variables. This can be seen by noticing that the forms $\epsilon (x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ and $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ are isomorphic.

We ignored the case of quadratic forms over fields of characteristic $2$.

$\bf{Added:}$

The general formula : let $Q$ a non-degenerate quadratic form over the field $F= \mathbb{F}_q$ in $n$ variables. Then we have

1. $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{
   \# \{ x\in \mathbb{F}_q^n  \ | \ Q(x) = 0\}  = q^{n-1} }$$
   if $n$ is odd
2. $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{\# \{ x\in \mathbb{F}_q^n  \ | \ Q(x) = 0\}  = q^{n-1} + \frac{q-1}{q}\cdot \mu(\det Q) \cdot (\mu(-1) q)^{\frac{n}{2}} }$$
   if $n$ is even

where $\mu(\cdot)$ is the quadratic multiplicative character of the field, $1$ on squares and $-1$ on non-squares.

---

Suppose we want to calculate the number of solutions of the equation

$$Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n) + a_{n+1} = 0$$
where $Q$ is non-degenerate, and $a_{n+1} \ne 0$.  This can be done using the previous results. Indeed, calculate the number of solutions for $Q(x) + a_{n+1} x_{n+1}^2 = 0$, substract from this the number of solutions for which we have $x_{n+1} = 0$, and get the number of solutions where $x_{n+1} \ne 0$. This equals $(q-1) \times$ number of solutions for which $x_{n+1} = 1$, which is the desired number.