# Number of solutions of an equation in $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I have no idea on how can we calculate $|\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb F_p^n: x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2\equiv 0 \pmod p\}|$ where $n$ is an odd integer and $p$ is prime.

Comment: Have you done some examples with two-three different primes and small $\,n\,$ , say for $\,n =1,3\,$ ...?

Comment: A [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183097/11619)?

Comment: I do not see the difference when $n$ is even? I think the best solution is the one that uses exponential sums, i.e $$\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}\cdots\sum_{x_n}\sum_te^{2\pi it(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)/p}$$ but which role has $n$?